# Update BCM5754 driver or not?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, drivers

I am running Ubuntu 16.10 on a Dell Precision T-5400. It uses a Broadcom NetXtreme BCM5754 NIC. The firmware is v.3.24 and the kernel driver is tg3. Using uname, the driver for the NIC is reported as 4.8.0-39-generic.

Lately, I have been experiencing a loss of Internet to this computer. I have ruled out problems with the ISP, the modem, and the router. If I cold boot the computer, after it is restarted, the Internet service is restored. This strongly suggests to me that an issue with the NIC driver is the root of the problem.

Checking with Broadcom, they no longer support the BCM5700 series NIC. I haven't checked with Dell support b/c it usually gives me a headache. I'm fairly certain that when I first installed Ubuntu 16.10, it installed the NIC driver it found to be most appropriate. Since it updates itself on a fairly regular basis, why hasn't the NIC driver been updated, or b/c it is EOL should I not expect it's Ubuntu/Linux driver to get updated?

Apologies for the long winded post and for sounding like a newb, but when it comes to the intricacies of Linux and Ubuntu, I am!

Post Script:  Believing in Due Diligence, I checked with Dell support.  Seems they only support RedHat or Windows.